# How to pass String Array As Formal Parameter to aspen SqlPlus procedure using callable stmt in java

Tags: java, jsp, sqlplus, callable-statement, aspen

**java Dao Code:-**

```
            String[] stringsArray = new String [] { "LC1", "LC2", "LC3" };

            CallableStatement cs = sqlpluscon.prepareCall("{call Get_Machine_Wise_OEE(?,?,?,?)}");
            cs.setString(1, machineparameter.getStartDate());
            cs.setString(2, machineparameter.getEndDate());
            cs.setString(3, machineparameter.getShift());

            cs.setArray(4, stringsArray); /* want to pass String Array */
```

Error :-

> The method setArray(int, Array) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, String[])

Details:- 
Using jdbc odbc connection with aspen sqlplus, same while calling with  variable (not array) it working fine.but with String Array am not able to call procedure . I request you Please Provide Solution i was tried many time still am not able to call .

Answer (score 0):

Just change your last line as below, where `typeName` is specific to type of elements array contains. if its string we can pass `varchar` or `text` for MySQL.

```
final java.sql.Array sqlArray = con.createArrayOf(typeName , stringsArray);
cs.setArray(4, sqlArray);
```

Comment: Hi jekin thanks for reply . i have update my code as per ur suggestion but am getting error mention below . can you plz provide solution.

Comment: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setArray(Unknown Source)

Comment: somesh, Can you please paste your updated code here and also sql procedure defination?

Comment: Updated Code:-( java )                                                                  String[] stringsArray = new String [] { "LC1", "LC2", "LC3" };
   
   final java.sql.Array sqlArray = sqlpluscon.createArrayOf("varchar" , stringsArray);
   CallableStatement cs = sqlpluscon.prepareCall("{call Get_Machine_Wise_OEE(?,?,?,?)}");
   cs.setString(1, machineparameter.getStartDate());
   cs.setString(2, machineparameter.getEndDate());
   cs.setString(3, machineparameter.getShift());
   
   cs.setArray(4, sqlArray); /* want to pass String Array */

Comment: Procedure is writen in Aspen Sql Plus :-                                                       PROCEDURE GET_MACHINE_WISE_OEE(usFromDate timestamp, usToDate timestamp, usShift CHAR(24), aMachines){ --my logic --}

Comment: just verify that custom type aMachines in your procedure should be created  as type of  varchar array or try to pass "TEXT" as typeName

Comment: i use to try "TEXT" AS typeName But Getting Same Error.

Comment: i create array in aspen sql plus like this :-                                         LOCAL machines;
REDIM(machines, 2);
machines[0] = 'LC1';
machines[1] = 'LC2';
machines[2] = 'lc3';    and i pass ' machines ' as a parameter to procedure in aspen sql plus.

Comment: Hi jekin i will wait for your rpl..!

Comment: Hey somesh, as per my knowledge , If you are getting same error than it  might be issue of your driver jar files rather than your java code.

Comment: Hi jekin am using jdbc4.jar for sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver .the thing is that it was working with single variant like int,string char etc but when i want to pass array then only it is showing error . so as you say driver is only one of the kind for the error or anything else. i really appreciate if  you provide solution.

Comment: Hi somesh , the thing which we can try now is get oracle.sql.array jar and used  oracle.sql.Array instead of java.sql.Array in above code. look below link for your reference

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-passing-array-to-oracle-stored-procedure/